# Recover href attribute in javascript function?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a problem getting the href attribute of a link. In have the following code in my DOM

```
  $("a").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    myFunction(this);
  });
```

In my linked js file I want to manipule the href attribute, let's say :

```
function myFunction() {
  var hrefValue = $(this).attr("href");
          alert(hrefValue );
}
```

But Is displays 'undefined'.

What am I doing wrong ?

Thanks a lot for your help !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You never accept a parameter in your function!

```
function myFunction(el) {
    var hrefValue = $(el).attr("href");
    alert(hrefValue);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Try using `.call` to maintain the context,

```
myFunction.call(this)
```

Comment: I always forget about `.call`